# Do we need some extension softwares? (Ex. TIO Chrome/Firefox extension)

Tags: discussion

We currently have a Graduation script, which adds some utilities. However, we do need (or want) some more utilities, like a TIO Chrome extension.

Do we need more? If we need more, How would we host them?

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for? And what do you mean how would we host them? Userscripts are literally plain text files, you can host them on pastebin for all it matters.  And extensions are in the stores for the respective browsers.

Comment: We'd probably host Firefox extensions on addons.mozilla.org and userscripts on GitHub (or anywhere that has "raw" mode and the ability to choose the final 8 characters of the URL). Chrome extensions are trickier, because you have to pay if you weren't there at the beginning.

Comment: Is it really that hard to open a new tab for TIO? I don't even use any user scripts, and I'm fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

We do not really need them.